# load a collada (dae) file into SCNNode (Swift - SceneKit)

Tags: swift, collada, scenekit

This works

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "house.dae")
```

Is there an equivalent for a node?

```
let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNGeometry( ..??.. "house.dae" ..??.. ))
```

I have searched high and low, finding nothing that will load an entire dae file into a SCNNode. (not just one ID from it)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you load a .dae file into an SCNNode in IOS SceneKit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356301/how-do-you-load-a-dae-file-into-an-scnnode-in-ios-scenekit)

Comment: maybe. here it was answered correctly tho. (load an ENTIRE dae file, not just one ID from it)

Comment: regarding this decade-old question, i fear the ONLY way to do this now, is as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75088130/294884 . Just glance in the file (with a text editor) and then it's trivial and smooth.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
// add a SCNScene as childNode to another SCNScene (in this case to scene)
func addSceneToScene() {
    let geoScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ball.dae")
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(geoScene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Ball", recursively: true))
}
addSceneToScene()
```

Answer (score 11):

iOS 9 introduced the `SCNReferenceNode` class. Now you can do:

```
if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Test", ofType: "dae", inDirectory: "GameScene.scnassets") {
   // ReferenceNode path -> ReferenceNode URL
   let referenceURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

   if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
      // Create reference node
      let referenceNode = SCNReferenceNode(URL: referenceURL)
      referenceNode?.load()
      scene.rootNode.addChildNode(referenceNode!)
   }
}
```

Comment: The best answer!

Answer (score 6):

That's what I use in real project:

```
extension SCNNode {

    convenience init(named name: String) {
        self.init()

        guard let scene = SCNScene(named: name) else {
            return
        }

        for childNode in scene.rootNode.childNodes {
            addChildNode(childNode)
        }
    }

}
```

After that you can call:

```
let node = SCNNode(named: "art.scnassets/house.dae")
```

Answer (score 1):

The scene you get from `SCNScene(named:)` has a `rootNode` property whose children are the contents of the DAE file you loaded. You should be able to pull children off that node and add them to other nodes in an existing SCNScene.

Comment: Note that you can't move the `rootNode` of one scene into a different scene. You'll need to pull out a child node instead.