# SceneKit - Loading a DAE into a SCNNode (unwrap error)

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm currently trying to import a dae file into a SCNNode that will then be added to a scene. I found some great stuff on here but I've hit a wall.

The answer I've been trying to implement was found here - [Stackoverflow: load a collada (dae) file into SCNNode (Swift - SceneKit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387604/load-a-collada-dae-file-into-scnnode-swift-scenekit)

I've tried to implement the top solution but I get an error which says:

> "Value of optional type 'SCNNode?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'

It may be that I've overlooked something very fundamental, I am very much a novice.

I'll include my ViewController viewDidload code below, if anyone could shed some light on this I would be infinitely grateful!

```
let scnView = self.view as SCNView
let scene = MasterScene()
scnView.scene = scene
scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

// enable default lighting
scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
// enable default camera
scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

var node = SCNNode()
let assetScene = SCNScene(named: "s185.dae")
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(assetScene?.rootNode.childNodeWithName("s185", recursively: true))
// Last line produces error
```

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: Apologies, the last line of code, scene.rootNode...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your `assetScene` is an optional. You seem to have got that part, since you're using optional chaining to access its `rootNode`.

However, any result produced by an expression that uses optional chaining is itself an optional — you don't know that `assetScene` exists, so you don't know if anything you tried to get out of it exists, either.

But `addChildNode` takes a non-optional `SCNNode` — you can't pass an optional to it. You need to unwrap that optional first. Even if you unwrap `assetScene` with an `if let`, you'll still get an optional, because you don't know if `childNodeWithName` found a node.

Try something like this:

```
 if let assetScene = SCNScene(named: "s185.dae") {
      if let node = assetScene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("s185", recursively: true) {
           scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
      }
 }
```

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation, it has deepened my comprehension. I am no longer getting the error. For some reason though my asset isn't loading, all I see is my grey background. It's puzzling, I managed to get it to display when I had it operating as a scene.

Thank you for your help so far though! Definitely fixed the problem I had at the time.

Comment: Just figured it out, my issue was the node name I was using to search with. I ended up getting the child node name using a println.