# Adding and transitioning animations in SceneKit

Tags: swift, animation, scenekit

I looked at Banana game from WWDC which is written in `Objective-C` was trying to convert the code to `Swift` for importing animation and transitioning between them but I am having problems running the animations in swift from DAE files.

I have exporter DAE files in both AutoDesk format from 3dsMax and in openCollada format. The Autodesk format the animation is for each bone so I am unable to call an animation by name so I just import the scene and do the following for the animation to start as soon as the file loads.

```
scene = SCNScene(named: "monster.scnassets/monsterScene.DAE") 
scene2 = SCNScene(named:"monster.scnassets/monster.DAE")

var heroNode = SCNNode()
heroNode = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("heroNode", recursively: false)!

var nodeArray = scene2.rootNode.childNodes

for childNode in nodeArray {
    heroNode.addChildNode(childNode as SCNNode)
}
```

Although the animation plays as soon as the scene starts I done know how to store the animation.

If I export the collada file using openCollada. I can use the following to run the get and run the animation as there is just one animation for the whole object instead of each bone in case of AutoDesk collada format. By this way I can store the animation also using `CAAnimation`.

```
var anim = scene2.rootNode.animationForKey("monster-1")
childNode.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "monster-1")
```

But then the character runs at an angle and also runs back and forth instead of running at the same spot.

Also the lighting is better using openCollada. I just would like to use openCollada instead of autodesk collada export. Right now I am using openCollada format for exporting the scene and autodesk for exporting character.

How do store animations in `SceneKit`/`Swift` and transition between them? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't change the default options when loading a scene from a file, all animations in the scene immediately and automatically attach to their target nodes and play. (See the [Animation Import Options](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneSource_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Animation_Import_Policies) in the SceneKit API reference.)

If you want to load the animations from a scene file and hold on to them for attaching to nodes (that is, playing) later, you're better off loading them with the [`SCNSceneSource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneSource_Class/index.html) class. In addition, you can (but don't have to) store your base model in one file and animations in other files.

---

Just look at this Bananas animation loading code. Just look at it.[*](http://boingboing.net/?s=%22just+look+at+it%22+banana)

```
// In AAPLGameLevel.m:
SCNNode *monkeyNode = [AAPLGameSimulation loadNodeWithName:nil fromSceneNamed:@"art.scnassets/characters/monkey/monkey_skinned.dae"];
AAPLMonkeyCharacter *monkey = [[AAPLMonkeyCharacter alloc] initWithNode:monkeyNode];
[monkey createAnimations];

// In AAPLSkinnedCharacter.m (parent class of AAPLMonkeyCharacter):
+ (CAAnimation *)loadAnimationNamed:(NSString *)animationName fromSceneNamed:(NSString *)sceneName
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:sceneName withExtension:@"dae"];
    SCNSceneSource *sceneSource = [SCNSceneSource sceneSourceWithURL:url options:nil ];
    CAAnimation *animation = [sceneSource entryWithIdentifier:animationName withClass:[CAAnimation class]];
    //...
}

// In AAPLMonkeyCharacter.m:
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)deltaTime
{
    // bunch of stuff to decide whether/when to play animation, then...
    [self.mainSkeleton addAnimation:[self cachedAnimationForKey:@"monkey_get_coconut-1"] forKey:nil];
    //...
}
```

What's going on here:

1. There's a custom class managing the animated character. It owns a `SCNNode` containing the character model, as well as a bunch of `CAAnimation`s for all of the things the model can do (idle/jump/throw/etc).
2. That class is initialized by passing the character node loaded from one DAE file. (`AAPLGameSimulation loadNodeWithName:fromSceneNamed:` is a convenience wrapper around loading a `SCNScene` from a file and grabbing a named node out of it.) That DAE file contains only the character model, with no animations.
3. Then, `AAPLMonkeyCharacter` loads (and stores references to) the animations it needs from the separate DAE files containing each animation. This is where `SCNSceneSource` comes in — it lets you grab animations out of the file without playing them.
4. When it's time to play, the monkey class calls `addAnimation:forKey:` to run the animation on its main node.

---

Translating to Swift and applying to your problem — where you seem to have all animations in the same file — I'd do something like this (vague outline of a hypothetical class):

```
class Monster {
    let node: SCNNode
    let attackAnimation: CAAnimation

    init() {
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(/* dae file */)
        let sceneSource = SCNSceneSource(URL: url, options: [
            SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyKey : SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyDoNotPlay
        ])
        node = sceneSource.entryWithIdentifier("monster", withClass: SCNNode.self)
        attackAnimation = sceneSource.entryWithIdentifier("monsterIdle", withClass: CAAnimation.self)
    }

    func playAttackAnimation() {
        node.addAnimation(attackAnimation, forKey: "attack")
    }
}
```

The key bits:

- `SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyDoNotPlay` makes sure that nodes loaded from the scene source don't start with animations attached/playing.
- You have to load the animations separately with `entryWithIdentifier:withClass:`. Be sure to configure them how you like (repeating, fade duration etc) before attaching to the nodes.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out. :D. sry cant even upvote your answer. Need 15 rep.

Answer (score 0):

### 2022 code fragment.

In terms of the swift sample in @rickster 's answer.

It seems the code is now more like:

```
let p = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "File Name", withExtension: "dae")!
source = SCNSceneSource(url: p, options: nil)!

let geom = source.entryWithIdentifier("geometry316",
   withClass: SCNGeometry.self)!
   as SCNGeometry
yourDragonNode = SCNNode(geometry: geom)

yourAnime = source.entryWithIdentifier("unnamed_animation__0",
   withClass: CAAnimation.self)!
```

In terms of how to get the "mystery strings":

"geometry316" and "unnamed_animation__0" in the example.

notice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75088130/294884

and: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56787980/294884